# What does 気持ちに寄り添う mean?

Tags: expressions

> 彼の気持ちに寄り添いたい。

I think this sentence means "I want to get closer to his feelings", "I want to understand his feelings better", but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an inherently vague expression (to me at least), but basically it is an expression of hospitality or willingness to be kind.

So your interpretations are not off, but it means more than just understanding. It means the speaker wants to share/understand his feeling so that it helps or consoles somebody in need.

It may be close to *to be compassionate* in English.

Comment: What does 寄り添う literally mean here though? As a Japanese, do you think of it as "snuggle up", "cuddle up"?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi Physically, 寄り添う means *to stay side by side* or *to come close/to someone's side*. 気持ちに寄り添う literally means the same about feelings, or like *to put my heart close to his feelings*.